# Adding colour to prompt stops updating current directory

Tags: bash, command-prompt, ansi-escape

My former prompt is this:

```
PS1='[\u@\h $(x=${PWD%/*}; echo ${x##*/}/${PWD##*/})] \! $ '
```

That is a monochrome prompt which will dynamically display the last 2 directories in the current working directory.  I changed it to this to add colour:

```
PS1="\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;35m\] $(x=${PWD%/*}; echo ${x##*/}/${PWD##*/})\[\033[00m\] \! $ "
```

The colour works but the directory doesn't change as you `cd` around the system.  Why not?

Comment: Are you sure you had double quotes on your previous prompt? I don't believe it works as you describe if you did. Did you perhaps have single quotes before?

Comment: You're right.  The original was single quotes (I couldn't tell because I was just echoing the string).  Using single-quotes in the second version solves the problem.

Comment: Don't use `echo` to see things like that. Use `declare -p PS1`, etc. It is more useful.

Comment: Alternatively, running `echo "$PS1"` once you set the broken one would have showed you the problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one with single quote works fine :

```
 PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;35m\] $(x=${PWD%/*}; echo ${x##*/}/${PWD##*/})\[\033[00m\] \! $'
```